# Best practice for adding captcha to user registration

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.1

I'm using Laravel 5.1 with [Bestmomo Scafold](https://github.com/bestmomo/scafold) for user account management and I'm trying to add BotDetect captcha by following [this quickstart tutorial](http://captcha.com/doc/php/laravel-captcha-quickstart.html). I was able to get it to work but to do so I had to modify the Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\RegistersUsers trait as opposed to the "ExampleController" that the tutorial uses.

I don't want to edit a vendor file, but I'm new to PHP so I'm wondering what alternative there is?

Answer (score 0):

create a trait that extends from the one that you need, make the changes there and make your class uses the new trait and you will never touch vendor folder.